# Promise rejection: Template parse errors:

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I would like add `ng-bootstrap` to my project based on `angular2`. When I try used modal component I have error

> "let-" is only supported on template elements. ("]let-part let-isOdd="odd">{{part}}

Where could be a problem?

Comment: No problem, add details.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are using ngFor, and wanna declare some local variable, you could using one of these formulas:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; let isOdd = odd; trackBy: trackByFn">
  // do something
</li>
```

Angular 4, you could do this:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i; odd as isOdd; trackBy: trackByFn">
  // do something
</li>
```

please take a look to this documentation:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html